# When should react-router match function be used?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the use of match function since we can easily match urls based on request url. Have gone through the react-router Server Rendering docs but wasn't able to get the idea. I went ahead and implemented server side rendering without using match function and didn't face any issues. Am I missing something?